# API request blocked and the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript, https

I have created an angular app using an api call. I have deployed it in github pages. Then when every api call I get this error message .

```
getList(input) {

  const url = '/api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=b6dba21fefcead3510c8ddf58eb57d43&query=' + input;
  return this.httpClient.get<RootResult>(url);
}
```

I the dev tool console I get this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://githamza.github.io/ngxs-app-example/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b6dba21fefcead3510c8ddf58eb57d43&query=l'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I'm using a relative path in my api but it adds always `http` instead of `https`

Here's my github page example : https://githamza.github.io/ngxs-app-example

Comment: Paste `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/` into your browser address bar and notice what happens: It redirects to the corresponding  non-https URL

Comment: Any solution ? Or it's a mess with the API

Answer (score 1):

Your API is behind http, so you cant call http api from your https (client) App, It violate the https security policy.. both app and api should be in same protocol

Update :
Change url to like following

```
const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=b6dba21fefcead3510c8ddf58eb57d43&query=' + input;
```

Comment: I'm using only angular , there is no java back end. I don't think that the article is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use https!

```
const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=b6dba21fefcead3510c8ddf58eb57d43&query=' + input;
```

Comment: Used, it convert it to a ''http" request